# puppetserver memory leak, why

Tags: puppet, jruby

Problem, memory leak
[image]

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

puppetserver                         6.17.1-1focal

config

```
JAVA_ARGS="-Xms1G -Xmx1G -Djruby.logger.class=com.puppetlabs.jruby_utils.jruby.Slf4jLogger -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1G"
```

Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: many times, on many versions. Some of my params: `-Xms7168m -Xmx7168m -XX:+UseParallelGC -Xlog:gc*:file=/var/log/puppetlabs/puppetserver/puppetserver_gc.log::filecount=16,filesize=65536 -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048  -XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError`

Comment: @azbarcea max-active-instances and max-requests-per-instance  What values ​​do you have ?

Comment: On a PE: `./orchestration-services/conf.d/orchestrator.conf:13:    max-active-instances: 5` and `./puppetserver/conf.d/pe-puppet-server.conf:66:    max-active-instances: 9`